# Cancel button is disable in the gridview when the delete button is set to disable

Tags: c#, asp.net

The cancel button of the gridview is not working when the delete button is set to disabled by the C# code (delete button is set to disabled if lbltype.Text != admin). So when I click on edit I cannot cancel the edit because the button is disabled See the Gridview image below

[image]

C# Code

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    lbltype.Text = Session["Type"].ToString();
    DataRowView drv = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (lbltype.Text != "admin")
        {
            LinkButton editLink = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[6].Controls[2];
            editLink.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && e.Row.RowIndex != GridView1.EditIndex)
    {
        (e.Row.Cells[6].Controls[2] as LinkButton).Attributes["onclick"] = "return confirm('Do you want to delete this row?');";
    }

}
```

Comment: It seems you're disabling everything under the 'Click To Edit' Column

Comment: Could you post or link source?